# Do same string character have same index if the string characters are repeated in the same string?

Tags: python, string

EG :  I Have a string s1 = 'ABCDCDC'

the index value of 2nd and 3rd 'C' character will be the same as the 1st 'C'? i.e 2?

Comment: No. Not at all.

Comment: Can y0u please explain this ?
s1 is the string 'ABCDCDC'

for k in s1:
    print(k, " " , s1.index(k))
A   0
B   1
C   2
D   3
C   2
D   3
C   2

Comment: What's surprising about `s1.index('C') == 2`? On the other hand `s1[6] == 'C'`.

Answer (score 0):

No. The index of a string refers to a specific position in it.

```
myString = 'abcdabcd'
```

on 'myString', the first 'a' has index 0, the second has the index 4.

Answer (score 0):

strings have a function called `index()`. This function only returns the first instance of the variable and throws a `ValueError` if the value is not found in the string. More info can be found on the [Docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html).

Basically how it works is that string.index() returns the index of the first instance of the value in the string.

So

```
'abcba'.index('a')  #0
'bcba' .index('a')  #3
'cba'  .index('a')  #ValueError
'cba'  .index('b')  #1
```